# What happens to the eigenvalues as we turn off the anti-diagonal blocks

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, differential-geometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

Say we have a possibility complex $N\times N$ block matrix $M$ given by
$$
M(t)= \begin{pmatrix}A&B(t)\\B(t)&C\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $A,B(t),C$ are $N/2\times N/2$ complex matrices and $B(t)=tB$, i.e. $B(t)$ is simply a matrix we can tune off to $0$ as we tune $t\rightarrow 0$. **What can we say about the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of $M$ as a function of $t$?**

I can see that at $t=0$ the eigenvalues and eigenvectors are those of $A$ and $C$ separately and I also expect some kind of continuity from $t=0$ to $t=1$, whatever that means.

I also see that at $t\rightarrow \infty$ one effectively has
$$
M(\infty)=  \begin{pmatrix}0&B(\infty)\\B(\infty)&0\end{pmatrix},
$$
which I am unfamiliar with this form.

Does anybody know anything about this problem? Perhaps references?

Comment: The continuity of the eigenvalues of a matrix is a consequence of the continuity of the roots of a polynomial (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/3217/georges-elencwajg) for example)

Comment: As $t \to \infty$, you could say that the eigenvalues of $M(t)/t$ converge to those of 
$$
\pmatrix{0&B\\B&0}.
$$ 
These eigenvalues are equal to $\pm \lambda$ for each eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $B$.